# The derivative of the Delta function times another function

Tags: reference-request

Good evening!
I can't understand how to prove that
$$\alpha(x)\delta'(x)=-\alpha'(0)\delta(x)+\alpha(0)\delta'(x).$$
I tried to use $$(Df,\phi)=-(f, D\phi),$$
also I used that $$(D(hf),\phi)=(h'f+hf',\phi)$$
but I got another result.
Thanks for help.

It would be very good, if you advised some books.

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: IMHO delta functions only make sense inside integrals, so try to stick it into an integral with a good function, $f$, i.e. $\int dx f\left(x\right).\alpha\left(x\right)\delta'\left(x\right)$ and integrate by parts, as already suggested by @AmIAStudent. Book-wise there is M. J. Lighthill "An introduction to Fourier analysis and generalized functions" and M. Rahman "Applications of Fourier Transforms to Generalized Functions"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kac-Moody algebra from WZW model via Poisson brackets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462119/kac-moody-algebra-from-wzw-model-via-poisson-brackets)

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of the Dirac delta works exactly through the integration-by-parts scheme you've mentioned,
$$(Df,\phi)=-(f, D\phi),$$
i.e. $\delta'(x)$ is the generalized function which returns for arbitrary $f$
$$
\int f(x) \delta'(x) \mathrm dx = -f'(0).
$$
Multiplying $\delta'(x)$ by some regular function is essentially equivalent to doing the same with $f(x)$, so that
\begin{align}
(f, \alpha \, \delta') 
& = \int f(x) \alpha(x)\delta'(x) \mathrm dx 
\\ & = -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[ f(x)\alpha(x)\right]_{x=0}
\\ & = - \alpha'(0) f(0) - \alpha(0) f'(0)
\\ & = - \alpha'(0) \,(f,\delta) + \alpha(0)\, (f,\delta')
\\ & =  (f,- \alpha'(0)\,\delta + \alpha(0)\,\delta')
\end{align}
as required.

Comment: Thank you! I understand.

Comment: @GIFT you should probably mark this as the correct answer.